# onClick doesn't work any way I use it

Tags: javascript, css, html, dom

The problem is that `onClick` doesn't activate the function. Below is my code. `quickPlay()` is for fading the first screen away:

```js
// Set up the variables

var playGradient = ["linear-gradient(135deg, #ff3b3b 0%, #ff8225 100%)",
     "linear-gradient(135deg, #edb052 0%, #ffe300 100%)",
        "linear-gradient(135deg, #b7ed52 0%, #00ffad 100%)",
        "linear-gradient(135deg, #52edcc 0%, #00fffe 100%)",
     "linear-gradient(135deg, #52aced 0%, #007aff 100%)",
     "linear-gradient(135deg, #8052ed 0%, #b600ff 100%)",
     "linear-gradient(135deg, #ed52e3 0%, #ff004d 100%)"];

var score = 0;

var level = 1;

var levelUp = [10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000, 500000, 1000000, 5000000];

// Start Quick Play when the button is pressed

function quickPlay() {
 document.querySelector(".mainscreen").style.opacity = 0;
 score = 0;
 level = 0;
}
function add() {
 score = score + level;
 document.querySelector(".score").innerText = score;
 if (score == levelUp[level - 1]) {
  level++;
  document.querySelector(".add").innerText = "+" + level;
 }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
body {
 font-family: "Montserrat", Arial, Sans-Serif;
}
.load {
 background-color: #34c6d2;
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #34c6d2 0%, #6284FF 100%);
    width: 100%;
 height: 85%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 position: fixed;
 color: white;
 z-index: 2;
 box-shadow: 0 15px 32px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.load-header-big {
    font-size: 100px;
 margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -85%);
}
.load-header-not-big {
 font-size: 15px;
 margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
 text-align: center;
}
.quickplay {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 width: 100%;
 height: 15%;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 position: fixed;
 color: black;
 z-index: 1;
 box-shadow: 0 15px 32px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.quickplay-title {
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 50px;
 box-shadow: 0 15px 32px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 background-color: #6284FF;
 background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #6284FF 0%, #8934d2 100%);
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-weight: normal;
}
.mainscreen {
 transition: all 100ms linear;
 display: block;
 z-index: 2;
 position: fixed;
}
.play {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 0;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.score-box {
 width: 100%;
 height: 75%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 position: fixed;
 color: black;
}
.score {
 margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 150px;
}
.add-box {
 width: 100%;
 height: 25%;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 position: fixed;
 color: white;
 background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #ff3b3b 0%, #ff8225 100%);
}
.add {
 margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainscreen">
 <div class="load">
  <div class="load-header"><h1 class="load-header-big">Press</h1><i class="load-header-not-big">This is a waste of your time.</i></div>
 </div>
 <div class="quickplay" onClick="quickPlay()">
  <h1 class="quickplay-title">QUICK PLAY</h1>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="play">
  <div class="score-box">
   <h1 class="score">0</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="add-box" onClick="add()">
   <h1 class="add">+1</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Whenever you press the button, it is supposed to trigger `add()` but does nothing.

I tried using an event listener and that didn't work either.

I was using devtools and `add()` works in the console.

Also, I need it to fade.

Comment: I don't see where or how is `score` or `level` variables increasing in value, they always remain 0 once you trigger `quickPlay()` function

Comment: Your `.play` element seems to be buried under the invisible `.load` and `quickplay` elements so it's not receiving any click events

Comment: ^ exactly that, change `document.querySelector(".mainscreen").style.opacity = 0;` to `document.querySelector(".mainscreen").style.display = 'none';` and it works.

Comment: @Lixus they reset to 0 only when `quickPlay()` is ran, which is a button press, not a loop. They change when `add()` is triggered (`onClick` of `.add-box`), if you see the `level++;` function and the `score = score + level` function. They update the text with `document.querySelector(".score").innerText = score;`, but I don't think it's a problem with the JS, because it worked when I ran `add()` in the console.

Comment: @vittore I tried that and it did not work. It also did not work when I tried that a while back.

Answer (score 1):

Answered by @Phil's comment really but here is updated version ( just use `display:none`):

```js
// Set up the variables

var playGradient = ["linear-gradient(135deg, #ff3b3b 0%, #ff8225 100%)",
     "linear-gradient(135deg, #edb052 0%, #ffe300 100%)",
        "linear-gradient(135deg, #b7ed52 0%, #00ffad 100%)",
        "linear-gradient(135deg, #52edcc 0%, #00fffe 100%)",
     "linear-gradient(135deg, #52aced 0%, #007aff 100%)",
     "linear-gradient(135deg, #8052ed 0%, #b600ff 100%)",
     "linear-gradient(135deg, #ed52e3 0%, #ff004d 100%)"];

var score = 0;

var level = 1;

var levelUp = [10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000, 500000, 1000000, 5000000];

// Start Quick Play when the button is pressed

function quickPlay() {

 document.querySelector(".mainscreen").style.display = 'none';
 score = 0;
 level = 1;
}
function add() {
 score = score + level;
 document.querySelector(".score").innerText = score;
 if (score == levelUp[level - 1]) {
  level++;
  document.querySelector(".add").innerText = "+" + level;
 }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
body {
 font-family: "Montserrat", Arial, Sans-Serif;
}
.load {
 background-color: #34c6d2;
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #34c6d2 0%, #6284FF 100%);
    width: 100%;
 height: 85%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 position: fixed;
 color: white;
 z-index: 2;
 box-shadow: 0 15px 32px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.load-header-big {
    font-size: 100px;
 margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -85%);
}
.load-header-not-big {
 font-size: 15px;
 margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
 text-align: center;
}
.quickplay {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 width: 100%;
 height: 15%;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 position: fixed;
 color: black;
 z-index: 1;
 box-shadow: 0 15px 32px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.quickplay-title {
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 50px;
 box-shadow: 0 15px 32px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 background-color: #6284FF;
 background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #6284FF 0%, #8934d2 100%);
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-weight: normal;
}
.mainscreen {
 transition: all 100ms linear;
 display: block;
 z-index: 2;
 position: fixed;
}
.play {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 0;
 background: #ffffff;
}
.score-box {
 width: 100%;
 height: 75%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 position: fixed;
 color: black;
}
.score {
 margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 150px;
}
.add-box {
 width: 100%;
 height: 25%;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 position: fixed;
 color: white;
 background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #ff3b3b 0%, #ff8225 100%);
}
.add {
 margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainscreen">
 <div class="load">
  <div class="load-header"><h1 class="load-header-big">Press</h1><i class="load-header-not-big">This is a waste of your time.</i></div>
 </div>
 <div class="quickplay" onClick="quickPlay()">
  <h1 class="quickplay-title">QUICK PLAY</h1>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="play">
  <div class="score-box">
   <h1 class="score">0</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="add-box" onClick="add()">
   <h1 class="add">+1</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: @Eliapple Techkid - fixed `level=0` in your `quickPlay` method, working now

Comment: I do want it to fade, would z-index after the opacity work?

Comment: Easiest way is to use some animation library and do it by hands. In the nutshell you are updating `opacity` property from 100 to 0 and then doing `display:none`.